# Would this buildup cause "dHE" error on an LG Tromm dryer?

Tags: repair, appliances, dryer, washing-machine, troubleshooting

Got the machine off craigslist. During the drying cycle it stops and shows the error.

The user manual tells that with  `dHE` error I should inspect the water supply, if the water supply is within spec, call service.

The service manual says it means "Dry heater error" and list this:

```
The Dry Heater is out of order.
- Replace the Dry Heater
• The connector of the Dry Heater is not connected
properly to the connector in the main PWB ASSEMBLY.
- Reconnect or repair the cannector.(sic)
• The Dry Fan Motor is out of order.
-Replace the fan motor.
```

Following the steps for each of the diagnostics, There's one step saying to open the motor propeler for the dry-heater assembly and check for foreign objects that may be impacting the rotation.

I didn't find any object per-se, but there is a lot of buildup there. Is it worth cleaning this up, testing, drying the machine again, or investigating further directly? I have zero experience with appliances.

I can't check if it impact the spinning while closed very well, as i can't turn it.

[image]